# Issues running any new android project - Default Activity Not found / Invalid Java package

Tags: java, android, android-studio

total noob with lots of issues with Android Studio.

1. Default Activity error
2. Invalid java package name

Getting a Default Activity error on any app or new project I run - below is an example of the AndroidManifest.xml

"Error running 'app': Default Activity not found"

I have checked more than 100 times I am using the right package names and that my activity is declared in the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.coleary.change;">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.coleary.change.MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/TicTacToe"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The package name is the same in the java code:

```
package com.example.coleary.change;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // use tictactoe code in our code for a new game
    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.coleary.change.R.layout.activity_main);

        //this activity(game) is a context within a main activity
        mGame= new TicTacToeGame(this);
    }
}
```

When I run the project I get the following error also:

Package 'com.example.coleary.change;' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'change;' is not a valid Java identifier.

I have changed the package name through Refactoring to 5 different names  to no avail.

I have spent over 15 hours hours trying to troubleshoot these issues and because I have the same issue on multiple projects / packages and apps I am completely stuck - any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon after `change` in your AndroidManifest. Package names can't contain semi-colons.

Comment: Thank you very much :) - The build now runs successfully but I am still getting the Default Activity error

Comment: Edit in your build.gradle

Comment: Thank you - I have updated the package & application id there too but still getting the default activity error

Comment: No, that's not right. You need to use the package name that was in your build.gradle.

Comment: Thank you ! I reversed my change and then  synced the gradle build and it worked - Thank you - you have made my day - genuinely thank you !!!!! :)